# Ubuntu server 10.04 wired network connected but cannot access internet

Tags: networking, server, 10.04

We had a problem with our server last week (Power supply), After fixing it the server is not getting connected to its static ip anymore.

I tried both methods (1) Using Interfaces (2) Using Network Manager

In both cases it gets connected, however it cannot ping any ip.

Since I cannot post more than 2 links ...

Here is the link to the album https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZ8Mr.jpg in which the following commands are bottom to top.

ifconfig

route -n

arp -n

lspci

resolv.conf

/etc/network/interfaces

Network manager trial  settings

Connection established

However, the ping always fails

I removed dhcp3-client just to see if it was interfering, did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this image

[image: network configuration]

you disabled automatic network configuration via [DHCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DHCP) (note that the method is “Manual”) and didn't configure a working gateway to the internet manually.

You should fix either of those issues. I recommend re-enabling [DHCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DHCP) by selecting it in the “Method“ combo box of the [network configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lgidg.png) dialogue window.